# Scripting GNU screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I've been trying to come to terms with scripting in GNU Screen. Upon reading the man pages and a few other examples, I understand that we can use the `at` command or the `-X` argument for sending commands to screen sessions.

Let me explain my situation. I need to write a script that runs from with in an existing screen session. This script should create new windows, set their titles, browse to a specific directory and run a program in each of these windows.

The problem with the `at` command is that I can only send one command at a time. When I create a new window using `at` command, it will not be possible for me to obtain the window number of that newly created window. Because of this, I will not be able to send any more commands to that new window. How can I retrieve the window number of this new window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On creating a new `screen` window you can specify a name with `-t` (e.g. `-t test`) and send commands via `-X`to this specific screen by using the additional parameter `-p` (e.g. `screen -p test -X eval 'yourcommand --yourparameter'`)

Comment: Thanks! `-t title` seems to be good. But I can't seem to run it using `screen -X "screen -t some_name"` from with in a screen session. It gives me a `unknown command` error. But if I do a `screen -X "screen"` it seems to work fine. Can you see what's wrong?

Comment: @Phani With `-t` you only select a specific screen window. For `-X` there are only screen related commands available - see the man page under "CUSTOMIZATION" for more details: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/

Comment: It seems to work fine when I issue the command without the quotes: `screen -X screen -t some_name`